# Size file is not equal after encrypt and decrypt

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

My file is 1 MB . And after i encrypt and decrypt it with AES-128, It is only 960 kB. Is it problem with my code?

```
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = new KeyGenerator();
        byte[] key = keyGenerator.generateKey(password, 16);
        System.out.println("Key :::::::" + Arrays.toString(key));
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

`
and next :

```
        byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(cipherModel, keySpec, ivSpec);
        System.out.println("cipher init done");


        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] inputBytes = new byte[64];

        int count;
        while ((count = inputStream.read(inputBytes)) > 0) {
            byte[] output = cipher.update(inputBytes, 0, count);
            if (output != null)
                outputStream.write(output);

        }
        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal();
        if (outputBytes != null)
            outputStream.write(outputBytes);
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();`
```

Comment: @kelalaka i updated it.

Comment: please remove the comments form the source code.

Comment: You can't call `KeyGenerator keyGenerator = new KeyGenerator();` There is no method of `KeyGenerator` that has signature `generateKey(password, 16)`.

Comment: First produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the problem. Then copy&paste the MCVE here. Do not type something from memory as your question.

Comment: Any exception? Are you reading the correct file? You may change the read condition to `inputStream.read(inputBytes)) > -1` and flush the output.. Without more insight, we are just guessing

Comment: Is the decrypted file readable or is it garbage?  If readable, then open the two files side by side and see where the difference is.  Is the decrypted file using a different character encoding?  Smart quotes take two bytes in UTF-8 while dumb quotes only take one byte in ASCII.